# Extra Comma in specific data field using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am combining very large data sets using python. The script works completely fine. However there is one specific row that may or may not have a comma in side of it. Does anyone know how to remove the comma? FYI this is how the data is collected it cannot be removed on collection. The field that it is in is the ["NAME'] field.

I have tried to implement a sep=r',(?!\s)' look ahead and that screws my data up even more

THANKS!

```
import csv
import shutil
import os
import pandas as pd
from os import path





def combinecsv(source_folder):

    all_files = os.listdir(source_folder)

    master_df = None

    for anyfile in all_files:
        if anyfile.lower().endswith(".csv"):
            file_path = path.join(source_folder, anyfile)
            print("opening file path: {}".format(file_path))
            df = pd.read_csv(file_path)
            if master_df is None:
                master_df = df
            else:
                master_df = master_df.append(df)


    new_df = pd.DataFrame()
    new_df["MSG_TYPE"] = master_df["MSG_TYPE"]
    new_df["MMSI"]= master_df["MMSI"]
    new_df["NAME"]= master_df.apply(lambda row: check_for_none(row["NAME"]), axis = 1)
    new_df["LAT_AVG"]= master_df["LAT_AVG"]
    new_df["LON_AVG"]= master_df["LON_AVG"]
    new_df["PERIOD"]= master_df.apply(lambda row: convert_period(row["PERIOD"]),axis = 1)
    new_df["SPEED_KNOTS"]= master_df.apply(lambda row: check_for_none(row["SPEED_KNOTS"]), axis = 1)
    new_df["COG_DEG"]= master_df.apply(lambda row: check_for_none(row["COG_DEG"]), axis = 1)
    new_df["SHIP_AND_CARGO_TYPE"]= master_df.apply(lambda row: check_for_none(row["SHIP_AND_CARGO_TYPE"]), axis = 1)
    new_df["DRAUGHT"]= master_df.apply(lambda row: check_for_none(row["DRAUGHT"]), axis = 1)
    new_df["LEN"]= master_df.apply(lambda row: combine_bowstern(row["DIM_BOW"],row["DIM_STERN"]), axis = 1)
    # axis traverses rows not columns
    new_folder = path.join(source_folder, "output")
    if not path.exists(new_folder):
        os.mkdir(new_folder)

    new_csvpath = path.join(new_folder, "output.csv")
    print("saving csv to {}".format(new_csvpath))
    new_df.to_csv(new_csvpath, index=False, quoting = csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)


def check_for_none(df):
     if (df) == 'None':
        return ""
     else:
       return (df)

def convert_period(period):

    y = str(period[2:4])
    m = str(period[5:7])
    d = str(period[8:10])
    t = str(period[11:16])

    periodnewformat = "{}/{}/{} {}".format(d,m,y,t)

    return periodnewformat

def combine_bowstern(bow, stern):
    bow_int = 0
    stern_int = 0
    if bow !="None":
        bow_int = int(bow)
    if stern !="None":
        stern_int = int(stern)
    return bow_int + stern_int


if __name__ == "__main__":
    source_folder = r'C:\Users\MTTA Standalone\Desktop\Code\csvcombine'
    combinecsv(source_folder)
```

Here is a sample of with and without comma data set:

```
MSG_TYPE,MMSI,NAME,IMO_NUMBER,CALL_SIGN,LAT_AVG,LON_AVG,PERIOD,SPEED_KNOTS,COG_DEG,HEADING_DEG,NAV_STATUS,NAV_SENSOR,SHIP_AND_CARGO_TYPE,DRAUGHT,DIM_BOW,DIM_STERN,DIM_PORT,DIM_STARBOARD,MMSI_COUNTRY_CD,RECEIVER
1,249830000,ZIM LUANDA,9403229,9HA2029,37.825850,-74.340755,2018-08-01 00:00:00.000,11.5,196.4,198,0,1,71,10.9,197,63,21,11,MT,D05MN-HR-CHIBS1
1,256819000,IOLCOS, DESTINY,9486049,9HA2936,36.833089,-75.672449,2018-08-01 00:00:00.000,9.7,93.1,95,0,1,70,14.4,199,30,13,24,MT,D05MN-NC-MAMBS1
```

Comment: Hello, It would be helpful to provide a minimal concrete example of the data. That we can ensure we have the full context of the issue.

Comment: just uploaded a sample

Comment: This is just bad data collection. The delimiter should **never** appear within a field. If it needs to, the field should be wrapped within quotes. If those rules weren't adhered to, sadly I don't think there's a simple way to salvage the data. You'll need to fix it after the fact, but it's going to mess with all dtypes upon importing.

Comment: Will there be any spaces in the strings? If not you can replace with a comma. If there will be spaces then there will have to be some heuristic

Comment: Also, your proposed separator works for your two line example. For a question like this, it's going to be nearly impossible to get a decent solution without a moderately exhaustive example with the edge cases that cause issues.

Comment: That's what I thought, the data is entered by users over an Automatic Identification System(AIS). If you are not familiar it is a Marine VHF system that transmits data. The owner of the vessel inputs the ship name and on occasion for whatever reason they use a comma. The data is then fed through "the cloud" to a SQL server, for legal reasons all data has to be recorded we cannot script into the database to only except aphabetical characters. I will just have to manual scrub the data. Guess I am up $%^&s creek without a paddle.

Comment: maybe it would be better to use quotation for all values instead of not using quotation.

Comment: Just as an FYI, when posting on Stack Overflow, try to only post code that pertains to the error you are dealing with. To someone trying to help, it's difficult to read through your "unnecessary" code. Might help you get some answers in the future :)